# Javascript bitwise operator "<<", ">>>" to Python

Tags: javascript, python

Below are some javascript codes

```
a >>> (c -= 8)) % 256
a = (a << 6) + f
```

Is there any shortcut equivalent codes for those lines in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no zero filled right shift operator `>>>` in python and we can not use short hand assignment operator in expressions (like `c -= 8`). So it can be written like this

```
(a >> (c - 8)) % 256
a = (a << 6) + f
```

Comment: So instead of >>> if i use >> and << should result the same?

Comment: @AbulHasnat Nope. Python handles negative numbers differently. So, `>>` itself is enough.

Comment: `(a & 0xffffffff) >> (c - 8)) % 256` should be used to get the same result with the javascript expression.

Comment: @falsetru Why to restrict to 32 bits?

Comment: Try `-1 >> 1`  and `-1 >>> 1` in javascript. Bitwise operators in Javascript treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits according to [Bitwise Operators - Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. [Python Bitwise Operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

From the Docs:

> The Operators:
>
> **x << y**
>
> Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits
>   on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as multiplying x
>   by 2**y.
>
> **x >> y**
>
> Returns x with the bits shifted to the right by y places. This is the
>   same as //'ing x by 2**y.
>
> **x & y**
>
> Does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding
>   bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.
>
> **x | y**
>
> Does a "bitwise or". Each bit of the output is 0 if the corresponding
>   bit of x AND of y is 0, otherwise it's 1.
>
> **~ x**
>
> Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1
>   for a 0 and each 0 for a 1. This is the same as -x - 1.
>
> **x ^ y**
>
> Does a "bitwise exclusive or". Each bit of the output is the same as
>   the corresponding bit in x if that bit in y is 0, and it's the
>   complement of the bit in x if that bit in y is 1.